# Starting Jetty 8 through arquillian does not start Servlet 3.0 App

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jboss-arquillian

When starting Jetty 8.1.17 through Arquillian my Servlet 3.0 Annotations do not get processed. The webapp seems to not work (i.e. @Path mappings do not respond). Deploying the same .war file to the standalone jetty 8.1.17 works.

Why?

I thought this would have something to do with the component "arquillian-jetty-embedded". This seems never to have been published for "8". But even when using it by building it local this won't resolve the issue.

While the sources are there: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-jetty/tree/master/jetty-embedded-8 they never made it into the maven central.

Furthermore http://arquillian.org/modules/arquillian-jetty-embedded-7-container-adapter/ implies that this would work for 7 and 8.

I also tried to add the container-dependency of

```
container 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.17.v20150415'
```

and using jettyPlus configuration. Still no success.

Comment: Oh btw, i'd love to use jetty 9.2, but the gradle Arquillian plugin seems abandoned: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-gradle-plugin Maybe it's not a good idea to use arquillian after all.

Comment: And the gradle jetty plugin is outdated beyond all means. I switched to https://github.com/Khoulaiz/gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin

Comment: Embedded containers can be tricky to know exactly what is being run because you don't have a clean classpath. Do you have the sane problem with a remote or managed jetty instance?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet.

Comment: the fixes for jetty 6 thru jetty 9 have been submitted to the arquillian project  well over a year ago.  no release by them yet.   why are you using arquillian?  standard embedded jetty is simpler, less work, and far more reliable.

Comment: Also, [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) now.